# Which situations benefit from Perl's study?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm playing around with [study](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html), a Perl feature to examine a string to make subsequent regular expressions potentially much speedier:

```
while( <> ) {
    study;
    $count++ if /PATTERN/;
    $count++ if /OTHER/;
    $count++ if /PATTERN2/;
    }
```

There's not much said about which situations will benefit from this. A few things you can tease out of [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html):

- Patterns with constant strings
- Multiple patterns
- Shorter target strings might be better (takes less time to study)

I'm looking for concrete cases where I not only can demonstrate a big advantage, but also cases that I can slightly tweak to lose that advantage. One of the warnings in [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html) is that you should benchmark individual cases. I want to find some of the edge cases where a small difference in a string (or pattern) makes a big difference in performance.

If you haven't used [study](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html), please don't answer. I'd rather have well-formed correct answers instead fast guesses. There's no urgency here, and this isn't holding up any work.

And, as a bonus, I've been playing with a benchmarking tool comparing two NYTProf runs, which I'd rather use than the usual benchmarking tool. If I come up with a way to automate that, I'll share that too.

Comment: I *have* used `study`, whether or not I *should* have used `study` is probably part of the issue you're getting at.

Comment: What were the results of your research?

Comment: I have no results. I wasn't interested enough to work out the code, especially since it only works for ASCII strings.

Answer (score 7):

Google turned up this [lovely test scenario](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~mikler/Courses/BioCom2011/labs/perl_primer/perlbio/exercises_part1/exer07.08):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# 
#  Exercise 7.8 
# 
# This is a more difficult exercise. The study function in Perl may speed up searches 
# for motifs in DNA or protein. Read the Perl documentation on this function. Its use 
# is simple: given some sequence data in a variable $sequence, type:
# 
# study $sequence;
# 
# before doing the searches. Do you think study will speed up searches in DNA or 
# protein, based on what you've read about it in the documentation?
# 
# For lots of extra credit! Now read the Perl documentation on the standard module 
# Benchmark. (Type perldoc Benchmark, or visit the Perl home page at http://www.
# perl.com.) See if your guess is right by writing a program that benchmarks motif 
# searches of DNA and of protein, with and without study.
#
# Answer to Exercise 7.8

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark;

my $dna = join ('', qw(
agatggcggcgctgaggggtcttgggggctctaggccggccacctactgg
tttgcagcggagacgacgcatggggcctgcgcaataggagtacgctgcct
gggaggcgtgactagaagcggaagtagttgtgggcgcctttgcaaccgcc
tgggacgccgccgagtggtctgtgcaggttcgcgggtcgctggcgggggt
cgtgagggagtgcgccgggagcggagatatggagggagatggttcagacc
cagagcctccagatgccggggaggacagcaagtccgagaatggggagaat
gcgcccatctactgcatctgccgcaaaccggacatcaactgcttcatgat
cgggtgtgacaactgcaatgagtggttccatggggactgcatccggatca
ctgagaagatggccaaggccatccgggagtggtactgtcgggagtgcaga
gagaaagaccccaagctagagattcgctatcggcacaagaagtcacggga
gcgggatggcaatgagcgggacagcagtgagccccgggatgagggtggag
ggcgcaagaggcctgtccctgatccagacctgcagcgccgggcagggtca
gggacaggggttggggccatgcttgctcggggctctgcttcgccccacaa
atcctctccgcagcccttggtggccacacccagccagcatcaccagcagc
agcagcagcagatcaaacggtcagcccgcatgtgtggtgagtgtgaggca
tgtcggcgcactgaggactgtggtcactgtgatttctgtcgggacatgaa
gaagttcgggggccccaacaagatccggcagaagtgccggctgcgccagt
gccagctgcgggcccgggaatcgtacaagtacttcccttcctcgctctca
ccagtgacgccctcagagtccctgccaaggccccgccggccactgcccac
ccaacagcagccacagccatcacagaagttagggcgcatccgtgaagatg
agggggcagtggcgtcatcaacagtcaaggagcctcctgaggctacagcc
acacctgagccactctcagatgaggaccta
));

my $protein = join('', qw(
MNIDDKLEGLFLKCGGIDEMQSSRTMVVMGGVSGQSTVSGELQD
SVLQDRSMPHQEILAADEVLQESEMRQQDMISHDELMVHEETVKNDEEQMETHERLPQ
GLQYALNVPISVKQEITFTDVSEQLMRDKKQIR
));

my $count = 1000;

print "DNA pattern matches without 'study' function:\n";
timethis($count,
    ' for(my $i=1 ; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
        $dna =~ /aggtc/;
        $dna =~ /aatggccgt/;
        $dna =~ /gatcgatcagctagcat/;
        $dna =~ /gtatgaac/;
        $dna =~ /[ac][cg][gt][ta]/;
        $dna =~ /ccccccccc/;
    } '
);

print "\nDNA pattern matches with 'study' function:\n";
timethis($count,
    ' study $dna;
    for(my $i=1 ; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
        $dna =~ /aggtc/;
        $dna =~ /aatggccgt/;
        $dna =~ /gatcgatcagctagcat/;
        $dna =~ /gtatgaac/;
        $dna =~ /[ac][cg][gt][ta]/;
        $dna =~ /ccccccccc/;
    } '
);

print "\nProtein pattern matches without 'study' function:\n";
timethis($count,
    ' for(my $i=1 ; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
        $protein =~ /PH.EI/;
        $protein =~ /KFTEQGESMRLY/;
        $protein =~ /[YAL][NVP][ISV][KQE]/;
        $protein =~ /DKKQIR/;
        $protein =~ /[MD][VT][HQ][ER]/;
        $protein =~ /NVPISVKQEITFTDVSEQL/;
    } '
);

print "\nProtein pattern matches with 'study' function:\n";
timethis($count,
    ' study $protein;
    for(my $i=1 ; $i < 10000; ++$i) {
        $protein =~ /PH.EI/;
        $protein =~ /KFTEQGESMRLY/;
        $protein =~ /[YAL][NVP][ISV][KQE]/;
        $protein =~ /DKKQIR/;
        $protein =~ /[MD][VT][HQ][ER]/;
        $protein =~ /NVPISVKQEITFTDVSEQL/;
    } '
);
```

Note that the reported gain is only around ~2% for the most profitable case (protein matches):

```
#  $ perl exer07.08
# On my computer, this is the output I get: your results probably vary.

#  DNA pattern matches without 'study' function:
#  timethis 1000: 29 wallclock secs (29.25 usr +  0.00 sys = 29.25 CPU) @ 34.19/s (n=1000)
#  
#  DNA pattern matches with 'study' function:
#  timethis 1000: 30 wallclock secs (29.21 usr +  0.15 sys = 29.36 CPU) @ 34.06/s (n=1000)
#  
#  Protein pattern matches without 'study' function:
#  timethis 1000: 32 wallclock secs (29.47 usr +  0.04 sys = 29.51 CPU) @ 33.89/s (n=1000)
#  
#  Protein pattern matches with 'study' function:
#  timethis 1000: 30 wallclock secs (28.97 usr +  0.02 sys = 28.99 CPU) @ 34.49/s (n=1000)
#
```

Comment: For what it's worth, any result with from Benchmark within about 7% is essentially the same result due to the uncertainty in the testing method, so this case isn't very interesting. I'm glad you found it though.

Comment: @briandfoy: yeah, it's mostly my point: it hardly seems to make any difference for this test-case, which _looks_ like it should be very appropriate. [Found the link](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~mikler/Courses/BioCom2011/labs/perl_primer/perlbio/exercises_part1/exer07.08), I forgot to add it in a rush

Comment: Ah - the link was there (I didn't forget - heh)  but you wanted the search: `+perl +(study function) +(benchmark OR profiler)`, 2nd hit. Not a lot else to go by though!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to leave notes as an answer, and later I'll develop it into an actual answer:

In *pp.c*'s `PP(pp_study)`, it has these curious lines (minus a comment):

```
if (len == 0 || len > I32_MAX || !SvPOK(sv) || SvUTF8(sv) || SvVALID(sv)) {
RETPUSHNO;
}
```

It looks like scalars with the UTF8 flag set aren't studied at all.

Comment: The 5.10.0 delta mentions that `study` was set to a no-op for UTF-8 data http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/pod/perl5100delta.pod

Comment: I wish there was a reverse index for the perldelta so I didn't have to look through all of them hoping one of them mentioned the thing I cared about.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. If you search, and most results are in Perl test suite, that means nobody uses it. Also, because of bug, you could only [notice speed benefits on global variables](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=7034). It actually brought some speed enhancements when dealing with English (sometimes even 2 times faster), but you had to make variable global.

It also sometimes caused [infinite loops](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=1761) or [false positives](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=92696) (`study` could add bugs to your program, even when it was just supposed to make it faster), and because of that it was [removed (or rather, made no-op) in Perl 5.16](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html#Other-notable-fixes) – nobody wanted to maintain a part nobody cares about anyway.

Answer (score 2):

None. Since 2012, [study does nothing](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/a58a85fab78d767203f1dac26cbf0717d0c47e87).

Currently the code has

```c
if (len == 0 || len > I32_MAX || !SvPOK(sv) || SvUTF8(sv) || SvVALID(sv)) {
    /* Historically, study was skipped in these cases. */
    SETs(&PL_sv_no);
    return NORMAL;
}

/* Make study a no-op. It's no longer useful and its existence
   complicates matters elsewhere. */
SETs(&PL_sv_yes);
return NORMAL;
```

which means that `study` returns true in the case where it would formerly have done something, and false otherwise -- but it never actually does anything.